# pg_dump / pg_restore doesn't restore TimescaleDB continuous aggregates (views)

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm trying to make an backup and restore PostgreSQL database with TImescaleDB based on article:
https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/backup-and-restore/pg-dump-and-restore/#backup-entiredb
I have several continuous aggregates. When I restored backup I lost my continuous aggregates - views. I got an error:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "time_series.test_data_hourly" does not exist
```

Comment: Does this look to be a similar issue? They found restarting Postgres fixed the issue and/or running `SELECT timescaledb_post_restore();` several times. Might be worth a look? https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1712

_Disclosure: I work for Timescale_

Comment: I'm getting the error on `pg_restore` step. It can't restore the continuous aggregates